# WordPress picks parent theme's home page template instead of the child theme one

Tags: child-theme

I have a child theme with its own home custom page template called "template-home.php" (Template Name: Home Template). I have a "Home" page which uses this template. Everything works fine as long as my Settings > Reading > Front Page Displays is set as "Your latest posts".

But if I set Front page as a static page and I set this page as the "Home" page (which uses the home page template), then WordPress picks the Home page template of the parent theme.

Why is that?

Extra info: the parent theme has the same "template-home.php" attached to the same "Home" page, and has not any home.php or front-page.php file.

Comment: could you clarify what templates you're using - a custom page template, or `home.php`? have you looked at the [`Template Hierarchy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) in Codex?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer as-written. What is the template (Parent) Theme? Does it have a `front-page.php` template file?

Comment: @Milo note: the `home.php` template file (used to display the *blog posts index*) won't be applicable in this case - though it could potentially contribute to the issue/confusion.

Comment: Sorry! I edited my question to indicate that I use a custom template. @Milo thanks for the codex page, I've just read it however I still understand that WP should display my child theme home page!

Comment: I am tempted to ask what would happen if you actually renamed your child theme template-home.php to front-page.php?

Comment: @Flick: "front-page.php" or "home.php" will only be used if "Front Page Displays" setting is set as "Your latest posts".

Comment: @drake035 no, that's not true. If it exists, `front-page.php` will be used on your site front page, always and forever, no matter how you have configured "Front Page Displays".

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the content of your `template-home.php` template file? **Also**: what happens if you name your file something else, such as `template-child-home.php`, and then assign it to the page assigned to display the front page?

Comment: I renamed 'template-home.php' to 'front-page.php' and now this template is used for the home page so that's cool! Thanks all. However I still don't see why WordPress insisted in picking the parent theme's template despite the existence of a template called the same in child theme.

Comment: WordPress doesn't override *custom page templates* the same way that it overrides template-hierarchy template files, as far as I know. I'll dig into `locate_template()` and report back.